# How to put a HTML link in URLEncoder message

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to create a String in java with a link in it.
The message reads like

```
String message ="Something happened please go back to <a href=\"link.com\"> Home </a> and start again";
```

This message is ultimately encoded using

```
String msg = URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8");
```

and displayed on a JSP page, but this message when rendered on JSP page looks like this.

```
Something happened please go back to <a href=\"link.com\"> Home </a> and start again
```

Plain String without a actual link in it.

I am not sure how to embed a link in a String message in Java.

Comment: How are you displaying the string in your JSP?

Comment: Why are you encoding a message as a URL. This looks like an XY Problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a lot like the issue discussed on this link: 
https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/lunatech%5Ewhat-every-webdev-must-know-about-url-encoding/#Donotuse%7B%7Bjava.net.URLEncoder%7D%7Dor%7B%7Bjava.net.URLDecoder%7D%7DforwholeURLs

---

The article says:

> Do not use java.net.URLEncoder or java.net.URLDecoder for whole URLs
>   We are not kidding. These classes are not made to encode or decode
>   URLs, as their API documentation clearly says:
>
> Utility class for HTML form encoding. This class contains static
>   methods for converting a String to the
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded MIME format. For more information
>   about HTML form encoding, consult the HTML specification.
>
> This is not about URLs. At best it resembles the query part encoding.
>   It is wrong to use it to encode or decode entire URLs. You would think
>   the standard JDK had a standard class to deal with URL encoding
>   properly (part by part, that is) but either it is not there, or we
>   have not found it, which lures a lot of people into using URLEncoder
>   for the wrong purpose.

---

I have formatted the relevant code from the page above and adjusted it with regards to your code:

```
String pathSegment = "link.com"; 
String message ="Something happened please go back to <a href=\"" + URLUtils.encodePathSegment(pathSegment) + "> Home </a> and start again";
```